# How can i prepare a phabricator revision for a new repository?

Tags: git, phabricator, revision, arcanist

So i usually have a feature branch and then `arc diff master` to create a differential revision off master branch.

How will i make a revision on a repository that has only the master branch?

Should i have started with an empty branch or commit to record the whole diffs?
Is there a standard way to do this in phabricator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use `arc diff origin/master` to generate a diff between the origin's master branch and your local master branch.
- You can move your changes to a local branch, as though you had started on an empty branch. This is a general `git` workflow and you can search for instructions if you aren't sure how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, these are git workarounds, that will absolutely work.I was wondering if there is a solid arc command that will generate a revision showing the whole repository or something.Also in a git workflow that autocloses branches after merge etc, the extra branches don't look right

Comment: There is no command to generate a revision showing the whole repository (no one has ever had a use case for this).

The `arc land` command will merge a local feature branch, then delete it.